# User role is grayed out when setting up another admin

Tags: chatter, user-admin

I am trying setup another backup admin user for our Salesforce and in the user setup area the role field is grayed out and below it the only option is for chatter?

Comment: Have you consumed all your available licenses? What if you deactivate an existing user then retry?

Answer (score 3):

May I know what  license have you assigned to the user? Based on the License you will get to see the profiles. You need to assign the 'Salesforce' license to your user. Then you will see the 'system admin' profile and be able to assign it to your user.